# What is the difference `bot_id` and `bot_user_id`? How can I get bot_id?

Tags: slack-api

I'm building multi workspace bot.

On oauth installation, I get only `bot_user_id` https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth#bots

`bot_message` includes `bot_id`.
I need to filter out the events which has same `bot_id` to my botself, but I don't know my `bot_id`. https://api.slack.com/events/message/bot_message

I tried `bots.info` api but it returns nothing without specifying `bot_id`, but I don't know my `bot_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `bot_id` and `bot_user_id` are different:

- `bot_id`: ID to identify a bot / app in a workspace
- `bot_user_id`: The user ID of a bot user

Every app has a `bot_id`, bot only apps with a bot user have an associated `bot_user_id`.

As you mentioned you need to `bot_id` to identify the app associated withe a [`bot_message`](https://api.slack.com/events/message/bot_message) event, not the `bot_user_id`.

You can get the `bot_id` from the API method [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) by looking for the entry matching your `bot_user_id`. It will be part of the profile.